# Using useEffect to manipulate DOM events not Responsive on different screens

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, parallax

Currently I'm trying to achieve the following parallax effect in React where my image is in a fixed position vertically but moves left to right along with text.

I've used useEffect to achieve this where I take the total height pixels and move my components accordingly. The problem with this is that it looks perfect on my screen, but as soon as I resize it to a bigger or smaller screen the layout gets janky. Is there anyway to have this same effect but responsive friendly. Feel free to edit the CodeSandBox

CodeSandBox(View in fullscreen for better reference): https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rumple-s8cr6?file=/src/App.js

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(false);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(false);
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(function onFirstMount() {
    const changeBackground = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
      console.log(value);
      let img = document.getElementById("moveLeft");
      let text = document.getElementById("moveUp");
      let text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
      let text3 = document.getElementById("text3");
      let text4 = document.getElementById("text4");

      let imgWidth = 280;

      text.style.marginTop = "-" + value * 0.5 + "px";
      text2.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 1.3}px)`;
      text3.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 1.3}px)`;
      text4.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 1.3}px)`;

      if (value > 600) {
        img.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 0.8 - 480 - imgWidth}px)`;
      } else {
        img.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 0.5}px)`;
      }

      if (value > 1400) {
        img.style.transform = `translateX(${
          -1 * (value * 0.8 - 1120) + 80 + imgWidth
        }px)`;
      }

      if (value > 1700) {
        setNumber(true);
      } else {
        setNumber(false);
      }

      if (value > 1100) {
        setIndex(true);
      } else {
        setIndex(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="middletext" id="moveUp" style={{ zIndex: "9" }}>
          Random Text
        </div>

        <div class="inflow">
          <div class="positioner">
            <div class="fixed" style={{ zIndex: "11" }}>
              <div id="moveLeft">
                <img
                  alt="passport"
                  src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="halfWindow" style={{ zIndex: "8" }}></div>
          <div>
            <div class="fixedText" style={{ zIndex: "7" }}>
              <div id="text2" className="text2">
                Random Text
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="secondhalfWindow" style={{ zIndex: index ? "10" : "6" }}></div>
          <div>
            <div
              class="secondfixedText"
              style={{
                zIndex: index ? "9" : "5",
                display: "block"
              }}
            >
              <div id="text3" className="text3">
                Random Text 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="thirdhalfWindow" style={{ zIndex: "4" }}></div>
          <div>
            <div
              class="thirdfixedText"
              style={{
                zIndex: number ? "10" : "3"
              }}
            >
              <div id="text4" className="text4">
                Random Text 3
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
```

Using vw instead of px should work but the calculations are really complex.

Comment: you shouldn't have to directly access the DOM by getElementById. Try refactoring it with using useStates to add animation since this might cause issues later.

Comment: @KoutaNakano can you show an example for the same in the sandbox

Comment: Why don't you use `vw` instead of `px` ? that might solve your issues. Full screen width is `100vw`.

Comment: @Tschallacka I tried but the calculations are very complex and I'm not really great at maths:(

Comment: Could you be more specific that on what dimensions on how does it look bad?

Comment: @ErfanNaghashlou So as of now you can see from the output in the sandbox itself how when the screen size is smaller the effect that I want which is shown in my picture above goes away. Right now this effect is completely catered only to my specific screen size. This is because I'm using px which will make the current content go further back on a small screen and only few px on a big screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a solution is refactoring your code.

1. to place all the elements in the center and create four sections.
2. define the center of the sections this help to find where need stop move image and move it back.
3. in the same way need to do with text.
4. when the window is resized all content is centered with *window.resize*.

Sandbox example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-bounce-mln0x?file=/src/App.js:0-615)

```js
function App() {
  const [screen, setScreen] = React.useState(false);

  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  // Reduce value if want the image to be closer to the edges
  // otherwise to the center
  const setImageLimitMovement = 2;

  const setTextLimitMovement = 4;
  const opacityRange = 400;
  // Speed text movement
  const speed = 2; // .5

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      if (window.innerWidth !== 0) {
        setScreen(window.innerWidth);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const app = [...ref.current.children];
    const titles = app.filter((el) => el.matches(".titles") && el);
    const blocks = app.filter((el) => el.matches(".blocks") && el);
    const img = app.find((el) => el.matches("#passport") && el);

    // Get the center point of  blocks in an array
    const centerPoints = blocks.map((blockEl, idx) => {
      const blockindex = idx + 1;
      const blockHeight = Math.floor(blockEl.getBoundingClientRect().height);
      const blockHalf = blockHeight / 2;
      return blockHeight * blockindex - blockHalf;
    });

    const leftMoveLimitImg = -centerPoints[0] / setImageLimitMovement;
    const rightMoveLimitImg = centerPoints[0] / setImageLimitMovement;

    const textLimit = centerPoints[0] / setTextLimitMovement;

    const changeBackground = () => {
      const value = window.scrollY;

      titles[0].style.transform = `translateY(-${value * speed}px)`;
      // IMAGE BOUNCE
      // Move to <==
      if (centerPoints[0] > value) {
        img.style.transform = `translateX(-${
          value * (1 / setImageLimitMovement)
        }px)`;

        titles[1].style.transform = `translateX( ${
          0 + value / setTextLimitMovement
        }px)`;
        titles[1].style.opacity = value / opacityRange;
        return;
      }

      // Move to ==>
      if (centerPoints[1] > value) {
        const moveTextToRight =
          centerPoints[1] / setTextLimitMovement - textLimit;
        const hideText = centerPoints[0] / opacityRange;
        const checkDirection = Math.sign(
          textLimit + (textLimit - value / setTextLimitMovement)
        );

        const moveImageToRight =
          (value - centerPoints[0]) / setImageLimitMovement;
        img.style.transform = `translateX(${
          leftMoveLimitImg + moveImageToRight
        }px)`;

        if (checkDirection === -1) {
          titles[1].style.opacity = 0;
          titles[1].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;

          titles[2].style.opacity =
            Math.abs(hideText - value / opacityRange) - 1;
          titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(${
            moveTextToRight - value / setTextLimitMovement
          }px)`;
          return;
        }
        if (checkDirection === 1) {
          titles[1].style.opacity = 1 + (hideText - value / opacityRange);
          titles[1].style.transform = `translateX(${
            textLimit + (textLimit - value / setTextLimitMovement)
          }px)`;

          titles[2].style.opacity = 0;
          titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
        }
        return;
      }

      // Move to <==
      if (centerPoints[2] > value) {
        const moveTextToLeft =
          centerPoints[2] / setTextLimitMovement - textLimit;
        const hideText = centerPoints[1] / opacityRange;
        const checkDirection = Math.sign(
          moveTextToLeft - value / setTextLimitMovement
        );

        const moveImageToLeft =
          (-value + centerPoints[1]) / setImageLimitMovement;
        img.style.transform = `translateX(${
          rightMoveLimitImg + moveImageToLeft
        }px)`;

        if (checkDirection === -1) {
          titles[2].style.opacity = 0;
          titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;

          titles[3].style.opacity =
            Math.abs(hideText - value / opacityRange) - 1;
          titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${Math.abs(
            moveTextToLeft - value / setTextLimitMovement
          )}px)`;
        }

        if (checkDirection === 1) {
          titles[2].style.opacity = 1 + (hideText - value / opacityRange);
          titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(-${
            moveTextToLeft - value / setTextLimitMovement
          }px)`;

          titles[3].style.opacity = 0;
          titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
        }
        return;
      }

      // Move to ==>
      if (centerPoints[3] > value) {
        const moveTextToRight =
          centerPoints[3] / setTextLimitMovement - textLimit;
        const hideText = centerPoints[2] / opacityRange;
        const checkDirection = Math.sign(
          moveTextToRight - value / setTextLimitMovement
        );

        const moveImageToRight =
          (value - centerPoints[2]) / setImageLimitMovement;
        img.style.transform = `translateX(${
          leftMoveLimitImg + moveImageToRight
        }px)`;

        if (checkDirection === -1) {
          titles[3].style.opacity = 0;
          titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
        }
        if (checkDirection === 1) {
          titles[3].style.opacity = 1 + (hideText - value / opacityRange);
          titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${
            moveTextToRight - value / setTextLimitMovement
          }px)`;
        }
        return;
      }

      window.requestAnimationFrame(changeBackground);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, [screen]);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={ref}>
      <h1 id="title" className="titles">
        Random Title
      </h1>
      <section id="block1" className="blocks">
        <h4>Block 1</h4>
      </section>
      <figure id="passport">
        <img
          alt="passport"
          src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
        />
      </figure>
      <h2 id="text1" className="titles text1">
        Random Text 1
      </h2>
      <section id="block2" className="blocks">
        <h4>Block 2</h4>
      </section>
      <h2 id="text2" className="titles text2">
        Random Text 2
      </h2>
      <section id="block3" className="blocks">
        <h4>Block 3</h4>
      </section>
      <h2 id="text3" className="titles text3">
        Random Text 3
      </h2>
      <section id="block4" className="blocks">
        <h4>Block 4</h4>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(220, 65%, 16%);
}
figure {
  width: 280px;
  height: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.blocks {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  color: grey;
}

.titles {
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  z-index: 99;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
}
h2 {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. I had 1 more doubt regarding this if you could kindly check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69029701/moving-fixed-content-below-and-above-a-100vh-component

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. make this effect available only for the screen width size you intended
2. calculate how many pixels you should move the passport depending on the window size of the browser.

The latter solution can make your application annoying to maintain because there will be so many devices to consider.

**How to get window size**

```
  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    x: window.innerWidth,
    y: window.innerHeight
  });
  const updateSize = () =>
    setSize({
      x: window.innerWidth,
      y: window.innerHeight
    });
  useEffect(() => (window.onresize = updateSize), []);
```

Comment: Can you please show an example for the latter solution with any 2 screen sizes in this Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rumple-s8cr6?file=/src/App.js ... I can figure out the rest of the sizes.