# Image not moving smoothly using translateX attribute

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Currently what I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Where the middle image stays in the middle vertically, but keeps moving horizontally along with text from left to right in a smooth manner. I'm using useEffect to achieve this for manipulating my DOM attributes. Currently the animation for the first 2 slides is working properly, but when I scroll to go to the 3rd slide, my image directly moves to the right without any animation. How do I fix this problem?

CodeSandbox(View in fullscreen to get a better idea): https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rumple-s8cr6?file=/src/App.js

Code:

```
const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  useEffect(function onFirstMount() {
    const changeBackground = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
      console.log(value);
      let img = document.getElementById("moveLeft");
      let text = document.getElementById("moveUp");
      let text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
      let text3 = document.getElementById("text3");

      text.style.marginTop = "-" + value * 0.5 + "px";
      text2.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 1.3}px)`;
      text3.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 1.3}px)`;

      if (value > 600) {
        img.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 0.5}px)`;
      } else {
        img.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 0.5}px)`;
      }

      if (value > 600) {
        setIndex(true);
      } else {
        setIndex(false);
      }

      if (value > 600) {
        setDisplay(true);
      } else {
        setDisplay(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="middletext" id="moveUp" style={{ zIndex: "9" }}>
          Random Text
        </div>

        <div class="inflow">
          <div class="positioner">
            <div class="fixed" style={{ zIndex: "10" }}>
              <div id="moveLeft">
                <img
                  alt="passport"
                  src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="halfWindow" style={{ zIndex: "8" }}></div>
          <div>
            <div class="fixedText">
              <div id="text2" className="text2" style={{ zIndex: "7" }}>
                Random Text
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="secondhalfWindow" style={{ zIndex: "6" }}></div>
          <div>
            <div
              class="secondfixedText"
              style={{
                zIndex: index ? "11" : "5",
                display: display ? "block" : "none"
              }}
            >
              <div id="text3" className="text3">
                Random Text 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="App"></div>
      <div className="App"></div>
```

In this code I've set it up in such a way that when the height reaches more that 600px, the image should start moving to the right smoothly.

Comment: Where do you set the transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you reach the window.scrollY of 600, your element is 600*0.5 moved to the left.

When you are at window.scrollY of more than 600, your img is back to it's inital place,

at this moment you have to move it back manually 300px (600*.5)

but you have to also consider that the horizontal displacement to the left, is between the inital place and the **right edge of image**

when you are moving the img to the right, you are actually moving it by its
**left edge**

so, you also need to subtract the width of your img which is 280px

```
  let imgWidth=280
  if (value > 600) {
    img.style.transform = `translateX(${((value) * 0.5)-300-imgWidth}px)`;
  } else {
    img.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 0.5}px)`;


  }
```

Comment: Hey I had 1 more doubt regarding this. Now I'm trying to move my image in my third slide back to the left again and now Im getting the same problem all over. Can you help me out as to where I'm going wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rumple-s8cr6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: honestly, the logic becomes way too complicated after 1100px, but i played around with it a litte bit and this works :    img.style.transform = `translateX(${(-1)*(value * 0.8 - 880) - 120 +  imgWidth}px)`; 
120 is 880 - 480 - 280

Comment: Wow thats a lot of maths XD. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hey could you kindly also check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920034/using-useeffect-to-manipulate-dom-events-not-responsive-on-different-screens thread. I wanted to make this screen responsive using vw instead of px, but the calculations are messed up