# Moving fixed content below and above a 100vh component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

Currently I have a fixed image on the center of my screen which moves horizontally on mouse scroll. I now want to add a screen above and below this component with a height of 100vh. When I try to do so, my fixed components move themselves to the top screen which I want empty. I have tried adding a margin top:100vh to the image but that moves it out of screen.

There are 2 things that I have a problem with here. 1 is how can I get this component in the middle of the screen after a 100vh window, and 2 is how do I have the animations start only when the user has reached that particular component. Because as my project is set up right now, the image and text move on user scroll, so if I add a 100vh screen above, the users scroll has started which starts my animations.

CodeSanbox(View in fullscreen for better reference): https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-bouman-lokt5?file=/src/App.js

Code:

```
{/* <div style={{height:"100vh"}}></div> */}
      <div className="App" ref={ref}>
        <h1 id="title" className="titles">
          Random Title
        </h1>
        <section id="block1" className="blocks"></section>
        <figure id="passport">
          <img
            alt="passport"
            src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
          />
        </figure>
        <h2 id="text1" className="titles text1">
          Random Text 1
        </h2>
        <section id="block2" className="blocks"></section>
        <h2 id="text2" className="titles text2">
          Random Text 2
        </h2>
        <section id="block3" className="blocks"></section>
        <h2 id="text3" className="titles text3">
          Random Text 3
        </h2>
        <section id="block4" className="blocks"></section>
      </div>
      {/* Stop Scrolling Animation */}
      {/* <div>Content</div> */}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this solution:

1. Get the height of the first element.
2. Hide the image and the first title.
3. Define when to call the action.
4. Add additional checks when showing or hiding.

Sandbox example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-bounce-mln0x?file=/src/App.js)

```js
function App() {
  const [screen, setScreen] = React.useState(false);

  const headerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const mainRef = React.useRef(null);

  // Reduce value if want the image to be closer to the edges
  // otherwise to the center
  const setImageLimitMovement = 1;

  const setTextLimitMovement = 4;
  const opacityRange = 400;
  // Speed text movement
  const speed = 1; // .5

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      if (window.innerWidth !== 0 || window.innerHeight !== 0) {
        setScreen(window.innerWidth);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const app = [...mainRef.current.children];
    const titles = app.filter(el => el.matches('.titles') && el);
    const blocks = app.filter(el => el.matches('.blocks') && el);
    const img = app.find(el => el.matches('#passport') && el);

    const headerHeight = headerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    // Get the center point of  blocks in an array
    const centerPoints = blocks.map((blockEl, idx) => {
      const blockindex = idx + 1;
      const blockHeight = Math.floor(blockEl.getBoundingClientRect().height);
      const blockHalf = blockHeight / 2;
      return blockHeight * blockindex - blockHalf;
    });

    const leftMoveLimitImg = -centerPoints[0] / setImageLimitMovement;
    const rightMoveLimitImg = centerPoints[0] / setImageLimitMovement;

    const textLimit = centerPoints[0] / setTextLimitMovement;
    // Hide when component mounted
    titles[0].style.transform = `scale(0)`;
    img.style.transform = `scale(0)`;

    const changeBackground = () => {
      const value = window.scrollY;

      // Init
      const startAction = headerHeight * 0.8;
      // const startToHideInFooter = centerPoints[3] + startAction;

      // Scale action to show content
      if (centerPoints[3] + startAction > value && startAction < value) {
        titles[0].style.transform = `scale(${
          (value - startAction) / 100 > 1 ? 1 : (value - startAction) / 100
        })`;
        // titles[0].style.display = 'block';
        img.style.transform = `scale(${
          (value - startAction) / 100 > 1 ? 1 : (value - startAction) / 100
        })`;
        // img.style.display = 'block';
      }

      // Hide image & title if header visible
      if (startAction > value) {
        titles[0].style.transform = `scale(0)`;
        img.style.transform = `scale(0)`;
      }

      // Hide first 'random text' when scroll above block
      if (headerHeight > value) {
        titles[1].style.transform = `translateX(0px)`;
        titles[1].style.opacity = 0;
      }

      if (headerHeight < value) {
        // Start scroll animation
        const mainValue = value - headerHeight; // reset scroll to start from 0
        titles[0].style.transform = `translateY(-${mainValue * speed}px)`;

        // IMAGE BOUNCE
        // Move to <==
        if (centerPoints[0] > mainValue) {
          img.style.transform = `translateX(-${
            mainValue * (1 / setImageLimitMovement)
          }px)`;

          titles[1].style.transform = `translateX( ${
            0 + mainValue / setTextLimitMovement
          }px)`;
          titles[1].style.opacity = mainValue / opacityRange;
          return;
        }

        // Move to ==>
        if (centerPoints[1] > mainValue) {
          const moveTextToRight =
            centerPoints[1] / setTextLimitMovement - textLimit;
          const hideText = centerPoints[0] / opacityRange;
          const checkDirection = Math.sign(
            textLimit + (textLimit - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement)
          );

          const moveImageToRight =
            (mainValue - centerPoints[0]) / setImageLimitMovement;
          img.style.transform = `translateX(${
            leftMoveLimitImg + moveImageToRight
          }px)`;

          if (checkDirection === -1) {
            titles[1].style.opacity = 0;
            titles[1].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;

            titles[2].style.opacity =
              Math.abs(hideText - mainValue / opacityRange) - 1;
            titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(${
              moveTextToRight - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement
            }px)`;
            return;
          }
          if (checkDirection === 1) {
            titles[1].style.opacity = 1 + (hideText - mainValue / opacityRange);
            titles[1].style.transform = `translateX(${
              textLimit + (textLimit - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement)
            }px)`;

            titles[2].style.opacity = 0;
            titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
          }
          return;
        }

        // Move to <==
        if (centerPoints[2] > mainValue) {
          const moveTextToLeft =
            centerPoints[2] / setTextLimitMovement - textLimit;
          const hideText = centerPoints[1] / opacityRange;
          const checkDirection = Math.sign(
            moveTextToLeft - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement
          );

          const moveImageToLeft =
            (-mainValue + centerPoints[1]) / setImageLimitMovement;
          img.style.transform = `translateX(${
            rightMoveLimitImg + moveImageToLeft
          }px)`;

          if (checkDirection === -1) {
            titles[2].style.opacity = 0;
            titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;

            titles[3].style.opacity =
              Math.abs(hideText - mainValue / opacityRange) - 1;
            titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${Math.abs(
              moveTextToLeft - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement
            )}px)`;
          }

          if (checkDirection === 1) {
            titles[2].style.opacity = 1 + (hideText - mainValue / opacityRange);
            titles[2].style.transform = `translateX(-${
              moveTextToLeft - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement
            }px)`;

            titles[3].style.opacity = 0;
            titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
          }
          return;
        }

        // Move to ==>
        if (centerPoints[3] > mainValue) {
          const moveTextToRight =
            centerPoints[3] / setTextLimitMovement - textLimit;
          const hideText = centerPoints[2] / opacityRange;
          const checkDirection = Math.sign(
            moveTextToRight - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement
          );

          const moveImageToRight =
            (mainValue - centerPoints[2]) / setImageLimitMovement;
          img.style.transform = `translateX(${
            leftMoveLimitImg + moveImageToRight
          }px)`;

          if (checkDirection === -1) {
            titles[3].style.opacity = 0;
            titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;

            // Hide image when scroll
            const reduceOpacity = Math.abs(
              (centerPoints[0] * 0.7 + (mainValue - centerPoints[3])) / 100
            );

            const checkReduceOpacity = Math.sign(
              (centerPoints[0] * 0.7 + (mainValue - centerPoints[3])) / 100
            );

            if (checkReduceOpacity === -1) {
              img.style.transform = `scale(${
                reduceOpacity > 1 ? 1 : reduceOpacity
              })`;
            }
            if (checkReduceOpacity === 1) {
              img.style.transform = `scale(0)`;
            }
          }
          //====

          if (checkDirection === 1) {
            titles[3].style.opacity = 1 + (hideText - mainValue / opacityRange);
            titles[3].style.transform = `translateX(${
              moveTextToRight - mainValue / setTextLimitMovement
            }px)`;
          }

          return;
        }
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
  }, [screen]);

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="header" ref={headerRef}>
          Header
        </div>
        <main ref={mainRef}>
          <h1 id="title" className="titles">
            Random Title
          </h1>
          <section id="block1" className="blocks">
            block 1
          </section>
          <figure id="passport">
            <img
              alt="passport"
              src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
            />
          </figure>
          <h2 id="text1" className="titles text1">
            Random Text 1
          </h2>
          <section id="block2" className="blocks">
            block
          </section>
          <h2 id="text2" className="titles text2">
            Random Text 2
          </h2>
          <section id="block3" className="blocks">
            block
          </section>
          <h2 id="text3" className="titles text3">
            Random Text 3
          </h2>
          <section id="block4" className="blocks">
            block 4
          </section>
        </main>
        {/* Stop Scrolling Animation */}
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(220, 65%, 16%);
}
#header,
#footer {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: hsl(220, 65%, 45%);
}
main {
  position: relative;
}
figure {
  width: 280px;
  height: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.blocks {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  color: grey;
}

.titles {
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  z-index: 99;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
}
h2 {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect and you make it so easy to use!!

Comment: Hey, so I updated the code with my actual text and now the text for the first title is a bit janky, as in it is to close to the image and you can see a part of it coming out when I scroll further down: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wilbur-f9vj7

Comment: I added additional lines in *css* to fix that and you can play with this yourself to adjusting. This happens because all element is positioned are centered. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-bounce-mln0x?file=/src/styles.css)